# Calculating totals in a PHP order form

Tags: php

I've created an order form and PHP handler. I'm really new to PHP. Just getting this form to work was challenge one. I have succeeded in that but now want to apply a bit more umph to the form. I would like to total the quantities of each poster ordered, then multiply it by the fixed poster cost of $30.00 each. I recognize that I need to insert a function that a) will total the quantities and then b) create a variable that is the result of multiplying that total by 30 for my sub-total. I'm pretty sure that once I have that process down, I'll be able to figure out how to apply the user entered tax rate (I'll change it from amount to local rate) as well as add the shipping for the total. I'm just completely lost as to where and how to apply the function.

MY FORM

```html
<form id="order_form" name="order_form" method="post" action="mail.php">
<fieldset>
  <legend>Realtor</legend>
  <p>Quantity &#40;minimum order &#45; 5 Posters&#41;</p>
<br>
  <p><input name="poster1" type="text" form="order_form" size="4">X Poster 1</p>
  <p><input name="poster2" type="text" form="order_form" size="4">X Poster 2</p>
  <p><input name="poster3" type="text" form="order_form" size="4">X Poster 3</p>
<br>
  <p><input name="ttlqty" type="text" required="required" form="order_form" size="4">TOTAL NUMBER OF POSTERS</p>
  <p>X &#36;30.00 &#40;US&#41;</p>
  <p>= &#36;<input name="subtotal" type="text" required="required" form="order_form" size="8">&#40;US&#41; SUB TOTAL</p>
<br>
  <p>= &#36;<input name="taxes" type="text" required="required" form="order_form" size="8">&#40;US&#41;  LOCAL TAXES</p>
<br>
  <p>PLUS &#36;40.00 &#40;US&#41; SHIPPING</p><p>= &#36;<input name="total" type="text" required="required" form="order_form" size="8">&#40;US&#41; ORDER TOTAL</p>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

MY HANDLER

```
<?php

$poster1 = $_POST['poster1'];
$poster2 = $_POST['poster2'];
$poster3 = $_POST['poster3'];
$ttlqty = $_POST['ttlqty'];
$subtotal = $_POST['subtotal'];
$taxes = $_POST['taxes'];
$total = $_POST['total'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$email_from = 'multistrandfilm.com';
$email_subject = 'Contact Form Submission';

$email_body =   "Qty Poster 1: $poster1.\n".
                "Qty Poster 2: $poster2.\n".
                "Qty Poster 3: $poster3.\n".
                "Quantity Ordered: $ttlqty.\n".
                "SubTotal: $subtotal. \n".
                "Taxes: $taxes. \n".
                "Total: $total. \n".
                "Message: $message. \n";
    
//$to = "quantumcadworx@gmail.com";
$to = "multii@shaw.ca";

$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers = "Reply-To: $email \r\n";

mail ($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers) or die("Error!");
header("Location: order.html");

echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='index.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Home</a>";
?>
```

I'm going to work on this some more and post my results if I have any issues. Thanks all.

Comment: Please adapt your post according to https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Most part is not needed to answer the question and makes it hard to read

Comment: The code or the description???

Comment: unrelated but you can use nested name for poster thing. `name="posters[1]"` and use foreach loop in php `foreach($posters as $posterkey => $poster){}`

Comment: PHP runs on the server, but you want to do calculations in the browser. You need to use Javascript for this.

Comment: So there is no way to use php? I thought I saw somewhere that php can do math.

Comment: So, you want to calculate the totals when data is input in forms before submission, right? Then @Kiko Software is right, you need to use Javascript. If you want to calculate the totals after submission then you can use PHP.

Comment: Thanks nullpointr... For now I'd be happy with results echoing onto a confirmation page after submission. I'll take it to the next level after that.

Comment: Sure you can echo the results on a page before user sends it. What confuses me, your form already sends a total sum ( $total = $_POST['total']; ). If you want to calculate after submission you need to remove it and just do something like $totalprice = ($poster1 + $poster2 + $poster3) * 30 . But still not sure if I got your problem.

Comment: You've got it. The total that is there is from a user entry, essentially they are doing the math on their own and manually entering it. I'll try applying your suggestion and post back my results... Thanks.

Comment: @nullpointr... Just to be clear, my form page will post results to the server side php handler which will display, in html, my confirmation page, this page upon submission will post to the mail handler. Correct? Three files altogether?